# iOS swift3 google map SDK custom info window is not appearing

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, gmsmapview

I am using google map to show custom info window.

I added code in `markerinfowindow` delegate method & delegate method is being called. But the info window in not appearing. Please help me to solve this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        print("width:\(marker.accessibilityFrame.width), height:\(marker.accessibilityFrame.height) ")
        let view = CustomView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:25, height:38)
        let intIndex = Int(marker.userData as! String)
        let entity = arrShopList[intIndex!] as! PharmacyDetails

        view.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(entity.fLatitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(entity.fLongitude))
        view.title = entity.strName.capitalized
        view.intTag = intIndex
        return view
}
```

Comment: are you get the result here `entity`

Comment: yes..i got it..

Comment: one more question why  you taken the coodinates from array, you can directly get from `marker.position.latitude` for fetch the latitude and longitude

Comment: ok. i will change and give it try

Comment: does not a problem ok try once